# How can we link python2 to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alias

Some time ago I used

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

to simply write `python` for having `python3`.

I noticed this alias breaks the package manager in some cases, so Im trying to revert this. I used

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
```

to remove this. But now I want to go back to default, meaning writing `python` calls `python2` and only `python3` calls `python3`.

Any idea how we can do this?

Cheers

**EDIT:**

By running

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 10
```

I managed to link python2 to `python` and leaving `python3` as it. is. Is this the proper way of fixing it? It doesn't seem like it...

**EDIT2**:

I just upgraded my system from 19.10. to 20.04., I have no problems anymore regarding broken packages, but this was probably the easy-way-out, I'd still appreciate a reasonable thought about how to resolve these python links well.

Funny though, I thought python2 is not used anymore in 20.04., but if I type `python` then python2 is called again.. how?

Comment: Just FYI, avoid using python2 if possible, since it is [no longer maintained](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer to this question on one of the [sister sites](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3), which essentially says to create an alias in a `bash` file (e.g., `.bashrc`).

The reason `python` is still installed in the OS is likely because people & programs still use it, though as Adam mentions it isn't maintained. Corroboration that it comes packaged in Ubuntu 20.04 and the program to change this without just changing a `bash` file (`python-is-python3`) is in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165365/779283).

Comment: Thanks Daniel Connelly for your answer, which give me more insight. Cheers